# Recursion function cooperating with another function python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to make a game solver. It should be able to solve Sudoku i.e.
find each possible number useable in each square.
This is what I have:

```
def next_possible_moves(board,row,col):
    possible_moves = set(range(1,len(board)+1))
    rows = set(board[row])
    cols = []
    for j in range(0,len(board)):
        cols.append(board[j][col])
    cols = set(cols)
    possible_moves = possible_moves - rows.union(cols)
    return list(possible_moves)

def solve(board):
    for i in range(0,len(board)):
        if len(board) == 8 and len(board[i]):
            print "Found a solution:", board
            return True

    for next_move in next_possible_moves(board):
        if is_valid(board, next_move):

            if solve(board + [next_move]):
                return True

    return False
```

Both are working, but I am not able to get them to work together. I am using recursion to make it use one number, and while going through the code, it will backtrack if it fails.

What I want is for next_possible_moves to use only one parameter, so I can remove "row" and "col".

Using a list with X lists inside, so it represent an "X times X" board.